# MODx How to add google conversion code to specific pages

Tags: javascript, tracking, google-ads-api

I'm trying to add my conversion code to my pages. 
I've tried creating chunks in modx but these don't seem to appear. Should I be using snippets for conversion code?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Judi

```
 <!-- Google Code for Call Me Back Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxx;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "xxxxxxxxx";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1041527068/?label=w_DgCMTStgEQnOLR8AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with Judy and figured out that we can achieve this through {{chunks}} just thought I'd update this incase other people wanted to know.

Thanks

Terry